# jquery not fading in row in table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the html of row in variable like this

```
var newRow = "<tr><td>test</td></tr>"
```

In my success function
I am adding this

```
$('.my_table tr:last-child').before(newRow).fadein();
```

But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.my_table tr:last-child').before(newRow).fadein();
//                                              ^----------

$('.my_table tr:last-child').before(newRow).fadeIn();
//                                               ^----------
```

As always, **javascript is case sensitive**. :)

---

**Update:**

You need to hide the element before you insert it:

```
var newRow = $("<tr><td>test</td></tr>").hide();
$('.my_table tr:last-child').before(newRow).fadeIn();
```

Comment: I have the correct syntax but it still not showing by fading but directly

Comment: i tried  this  `$(newRow).hide();`  but still i can see any fade effect

Comment: jsfiddle is blocked by our company firewall

Comment: If i use this   `var newRow = $(newRow).hide();` then my row ias not getting added at all not even in firebug

Comment: i think i found the problem , you are fading in the wrong element . This thing worked for me  `$('.my_table tr:last-child').prev().fadeIn()`

Answer (score 0):

Check This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NgDh5/)

```
$('#addNewRow').on('click',function(){
   var newRow = $("<tr><td>test</td></tr>");
   newRow.hide();
   $('.my_table tr:last-child').before(newRow);
   newRow.fadeIn("slow");
});
```